# I cannot install Google extensions on Brave

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, brave

I'm not able to install Google extensions on Brave, I'm using Version 1.26.67 Chromium version: 91.0.4472.114 (Official Build) (64-bit) in a Contabo Windowns Server 2019.

"An error has occurred
Access denied."

Does anyone have the same problem? Or somehow managed to solve?

[presented error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyfiA.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Appears to be effecting more people than just you](https://www.reddit.com/r/brave_browser/comments/o7fkgb/cannot_install_extensions/) which suggests (but does not confirm) the issues is not on your end

Comment: Thank you partner, i was 2h banging my head here, when went looking for help here, they resolved, something happened on the Brave server, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found on GitHub the answer [link](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/16611), it was a problem on the Brave server, it has already been resolved.